# Find source MongoConnectionPool.cs MongoDB Exception VB.net

Tags: php, vb.net, mongodb

I have a program to Update MongoDB automatically using VB.net

Where Exception: A first chance exception of type 'System.TimeoutException' occurred in MongoDB.Driver.dll

My code add try catch but this error not catch

this is my code

```
 Try
                            For Each ReturnedDocument In ListCollectionBusinessCursorForThisStepping
                                Dim abusiness = New Business(ReturnedDocument)
                                Dim businessBson = abusiness.ToBsonDocument
                                appendToTextFile(businessBson.ToString + vbNewLine, "IndexContentquery.txt")
                                collection.Save(businessBson)
                                counter += 1
                            Next ReturnedDocument
                        Catch ex As Exception
                            LogException(ex)
                            appendToTextFile("Some error at" + CStr(starts) + "+" + CStr(counter) + vbNewLine, "messedup.txt", ForAppending)
                        End Try
```

What confuses me is why it asked for some .cs file? I am using vb.net. I don't have the cs file. Is there a mongodb driver with cs files? Should I get cs files of mongodb driver?

here is screenshot
[image]

The code works most of the time. Sometimes it just happen.

Comment: Can you please add the connection strings that you use?

Comment: Chances are your connection string is wrong or your servers aren't running.  Regardless, as daveH mentioned, it's looking for the source file in order to let you step into the driver code.  You have some settings enabled to do that.  If you do not like those settings, turn on "Just My Code" in the debug settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jim Thio,

It is asking you to find the .cs file as you have selected the debug option and visual studio is trying to locate the source code used to compile the object which raised the original exception.

Comment: Hmm... but it's dll.. How do I avoid this behavior?

Comment: Try catching the System.TimeoutException or confirm that you are able to connect to our mongod instance from your app